# Eye of the Storm—Simultaneous or Sequential?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Eye of the Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEye%20of%20the%20Storm%5d) and [Thousand-Year Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThousand-Year%20Storm%5d) on the battlefield, I cast [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d). Storm count goes to one, and Eye exiles the Bolt. Through Eye, I copy and recast it, and Thousand-Year Storm copies it once. Storm count to two. This much makes sense.

Now I cast [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d). Copied twice, the original is exiled, and my storm count goes to three. Now Eye copies both Shock and Bolt. Are these two cast in order (so one is copied three times and the other four), or do I cast them simultaneously, only choosing their order on the stack (and copying each only three times)?

Comment: There is nothing in MtG that casts multiple different spells simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequential.

"The player may cast the copies" would simultaneously cast the copies. This is practically impossible to do (since casting is a long and complex procedure), so the card uses the wording "For each copy, the player may cast the copy" instead. The instruction only has you cast a single object, so there's nothing for it to be simultaneous with.

Comment: That said, I *think* that you can stack the Thousand Year Storm triggers in any order. Is that right?

Comment: @Arcanist Lupus, Yes. The abilities are only added to the stack the next time a player would get priority. At that point, multiple instances of TYS's triggered ability will need to be added to the stack. Each player in APNAP order adds their triggered abilities to the stack in the order they choose.

Comment: Not that APNAP order matters when one player controls all the triggers.  (I mean, it could matter if there are other triggers in play.  But just the scenario as described only features triggers from a single player at a time.)

Comment: Right. I was just being complete.

Comment: _"since casting is a long and complex procedure"_ -- what does that refer to? Surely you can cast an Instant or a Sorcery by just tapping some mana, showing the card and declaring targets? (plus whatever other choices there are) Doesn't seem too complex.

Comment: [Rule 601.2](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Casting_spells) describes the 9 step process to cast a spell. And a couple of those steps are whole paragraphs. In normal gameplay, that is usually equivalent to what you describe, but it can get more complicated.

Comment: Not to mention that one can activate other abilities add part of casting spells. How can that all be done simultaneously? Do you do each step simultaneously? What happens if there's a conflict? How do you handle both castings trying to tap the same land? How do you handle reversions? Etc etc etc.